# Is it legal to publish schematics from reversed engineered electronics?

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property

If I were to analyze an electronic device and reproduce the circuit schematics, would it be legal to publish the schematic?

I know that there might be issues with selling a clone but I am not so sure of the schematics themselves.

Comment: You'll find elements to answer your question here : https://www.eff.org/issues/coders/reverse-engineering-faq

Comment: If you purchased a device without license restrictions, you are certainly free to take it apart and try to find out how it works. Publishing such information would not be a copyright infringement nor a patent infringement, nor violation of trade secrets, so it's not clear why it would NOT be legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unless your acquisition of the device was under a license containing restrictions on your use, such as non-disclosure, or reverse engineering, your publication of schematics would not necessarily violate that license, let alone patent laws or copyright laws applicable to the general public.

Patent laws mainly permit the owners to prevent you from making, using, selling or importing an infringement (or inducing infringement) and copyright laws do not cover any "idea, procedure, process, system, method of operation, concept, principle, or discovery". 17 USC § 102(b).

Comment: As far as I know, patents need to be published, together with documentation of how the invention has been implemented. This is in so far mandatory, as only what has been documented (or prototyped) within the patent application can be patented. Additionally, the paten's task is, to inform other inventors of protected implementations what should protect them from unintentionally infringing patents.
The conclusion of this is, that each and every patent has already been published by it's holder, therefore you are not publicising secret knowledge if you publish your findings.

Comment: Yes, patents (and most patent applications) are published (literally "the primary purpose of a  patent").  Many products that contain "patented inventions" may also implement various "trade secrets" that were not disclosed in the initial patents.  Unless you have personally agreed to keep them confidential (e.g., restricted beta tester), then publishing the results of reverse engineering a product sold to the public should still be legal.